# Linq in entity framework

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I am having trouble with a select with a select.

The select query in () which is selecting the userid is not liked by the IDE. How do you accomplish a select within a select?

```
Dim newctx As teckModel.teckEntities
        Dim pending = From c In newctx.my_aspnet_membership Where c.userId = (From c In newctx.my_aspnet_usersinroles Where c.roleId = 8 Select c.userId) Select c.Email, c.CreationDate, c.LastLoginDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equals operator assumes a single value, but the second linq statement is returning an IEnumerable. You should use `.Contains()` on the IEnumerable or further refine the subquery to return only a single entity.

```
var pending = from x in newctx.my_aspnet_membership where
    (from y in newctx.my_aspnet_usersinroles where y.roleId==8 select y.userId).Contains(x.userId)
    select new { x.Email, x.CreationDate, x.LastLoginDate };
```

Comment: Thank you. I want to add an additional select from another table where the id from that table equals the userid i want to capture the name from that table. How do I nest that within so that I'm retrieving 4 values, name and the three from prior query?

Comment: An extra question is should I be getting all the fields from the userid and only using the ones I require in my gridview?

Comment: You can use `Join` to "nest" the second table rather than using a subquery. This should remain efficient as long as you're only enumerating the IEnumerable once.

Answer (score 1):

You can either do a `Contain` or `Any` or you'll have to use `FirstOrDefault`

```
Where (From c In newctx.my_aspnet_usersinroles Where c.roleId = 8 Select c.userId).Contains(c.userId)
```

or

```
c.userId == (From c In newctx.my_aspnet_usersinroles Where c.roleId = 8 Select c.userId).FirstOrDefault()
```